# Как уместить контент на одну страницу при печати для альбомной и книжной ориентации?

Tags: css

Для печати генерируется страница, которая содержит изображение. Необходимо уместить эту страницу на один лист А4. Предположим, я задал стиль с размером листа для печати, но он рассчитан на книжную ориентацию листа. При смене пользователем ориентации листа для печати на альбомную образуются лишние пустые страницы. Как можно задать размер А4 для альбомной и для книжной ориентации при печати отдельно, чтобы в обоих случаях размер контента подгонялся под А4?
Т.е. `{width: 21cm; height: 29.7cm;}`  и соответственно `{height: 21cm; width: 29.7cm;}`.

```
function prnWindow (_title, _url) {
    var nw = window.open(_url);
        nw.document.write('<html><head><title>' + _title + '</title>');
        nw.document.write('<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>');
        nw.document.write('<style> @media print { body {width: 21cm; height: 29.7cm;} { #imgcontainer { vertical-align: middle;} }</style>');
        nw.document.write('<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>');
        nw.document.write('</head>');
        nw.document.write('<body>');
        nw.document.write('   <div class="container-fluid" style="">');
        nw.document.write('      <nav class="navbar" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">');
        nw.document.write('         <div>');
        nw.document.write('            <ul class="pull-left nav navbar-nav">');
        nw.document.write('              <li>');
        nw.document.write('                 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="print();">');
        nw.document.write('                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>Печать');
        nw.document.write('                 </button>');
        nw.document.write('              </li>');
        nw.document.write('            </ul>');
        nw.document.write('         </div>');
        nw.document.write('      </nav>');
        nw.document.write('      <div style="display: table; height: 100%;">');
        nw.document.write('         <div id="imgcontainer" style="display: table-cell;"><img src="' + _url + '"/></div>');
        nw.document.write('      </div>');
        nw.document.write('   </div>');
        nw.document.write('</body>');
        nw.document.write('</html>');
        nw.document.close();
        nw.focus();
}
```

Стили прописал (см. ответ ниже).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Книжная ориентация шаблона */
@media print and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Стили для книжной ориентации шаблона */
}
/* Альбомная ориентация шаблона*/
@media print and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Стили для альбомной ориентации шаблона */
}
```

Comment: Ответ выше неверный. Вас попросили уместить контент на одну страницу. Чтобы он при печати не разделился на 2 страницы.
Либо человек неправильно задал вопрос.